# select by name and array value with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I thought that i could do this:

```
i[1] = 23; // this is built from a regex

$('select [name="sys_map\\['+i[1]+'\\]"]').css('border-color', '#FF5C5C');
```

or maybe

```
$('select [name=sys_map\\['+i[1]+'\\]]').css('border-color', '#FF5C5C');
```

to select

```
<select name="sys_map[23]">
```

quoting the name shows error:

> [15:36:27.647] Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select
>   [name="sys_map[1]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a space between 'select' and the name attribute selector, so you're looking for elements that match the attribute selector which are descendants of the `select`.

Change

```
$('select [name="sys_map\\['+i[1]+'\\]"]')
```

To

```
$('select[name="sys_map['+i[1]+']"]')
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NyAkm/

Note I had to change your array definition:

```
var i = [];
i[1] = 23;
```

Comment: dang it.. now i feel stupid... I have looked at so many QA's and was focusing on the brackets, backslashes and quotes.. did not realize the space.... Thanks.

Comment: @SmithSmithy Happens to everyone. Also, looks like ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ is correct, the slashes aren't needed. http://jsfiddle.net/NyAkm/

Comment: hopefully someone else stumbles on this and it helps

Comment: If you don't have the quotes you need the to escape the `[`